# Проблема с кодировкой UTF

Tags: php

Разрабатываю ссылки аналогичные в социальных сетях. Получаю метаданные для этих ссылок.

Для примера использовал 2 крупных сайта. **znak.com** и **ria.ru**
У обоих кодировка одинаковая: **UTF-8**

Но почему-то один **ria.ru** возвращает данные в UTF, а **znak.com** нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$c = file_get_contents($matches[0]);
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);

    foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:title']") as $el) {
      $og_title = htmlentities($el->getAttribute("content"), ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:description']") as $el) {
      $og_description = htmlentities($el->getAttribute("content"), ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:image']") as $el) {
      $og_image = htmlentities($el->getAttribute("content"), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте лучше запрос через `curl` вместо `file_get_contents`. И попробуйте применить эти строчки кода `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");` `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`